# Filter on a list of tags

Tags: django, google-app-engine, filter, multi-query

I'm trying to select all the songs in my Django database whose tag is any of those in a given list. There is a Song model, a Tag model, and a SongTag model (for the many to many relationship).

This is my attempt:

```
taglist = ["cool", "great"]
tags = Tag.objects.filter(name__in=taglist).values_list('id', flat=True)
song_tags = SongTag.objects.filter(tag__in=list(tags))
```

At this point I'm getting an error:

```
DatabaseError: MultiQuery does not support keys_only.
```

What am I getting wrong? If you can suggest a completely different approach to the problem, it would be more than welcome too!

EDIT: I should have mentioned I'm using Django on **Google AppEngine** with django-nonrel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't use m2m relationship with AppEngine. NoSQL databases (and BigTable is one of them) generally don't support JOINs, and programmer is supposed to denormalize the data structure. This is a deliberate design desicion: while your database will contain redundant data, your read queries will be much simpler (no need to combine data from 3 tables), which in turn makes the design of DB server much simpler as well (of course this is made for the sake of optimization and scaling)

In your case you should probably get rid of Tag and SongTag models, and just store the tag in the Song model as a string. I of course assume that Tag model only contains id and name, if Tag in fact contains more data, you should still have Tag model. Song model in that case should contain both tag_id and tag_name. The idea, as I explained above, is to introduce redundancy for the sake of simpler queries

Comment: Aha! Great answer, it helped me understanding. You are correct in assuming that Tag model only stores an ID and a name. Now, what if a song has more than one tag (as is does)? What would be the NoSQL approach to this? Many thanks!

Comment: @gozzilli I guess you should use ListField instead of CharField (I assume you're using [django-nonrel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel) with [djangoappengine](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine) backend. If not, look [there](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine#installation) for installation instructions. Support for ListField is [added](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine#field-types) by djangoappengine)

Comment: Oh, and the documentation for django-nonrel is a bit lacking, so if you have questions about ListField, I guess you should search in [django-nonrel maillist](http://groups.google.com/group/django-non-relational) for now.

Comment: yeah I'm using django-nonrel + djangoappengine. Many thanks for your pointers!

Answer (score 4):

Please, please let the ORM build the query for you:

```
song_tags = SongTag.objects.filter(tag__name__in = taglist)
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I edited your answer by error. I rolled back so it should be OK now.

Comment: If I do that I get a "DatabaseError: This query is not supported by the database." I should have probably mentioned that I'm using Google Appengine. Does that matter? If so, is there any way round the problem?

Comment: Oh, yeah, that makes a huge difference.  Appengine's database is not SQL, and the ORM supplied with the Appengine version of Django is very different from anything you'll find in a book on stock Django.  I strongly suggest reading [Google App Engine: Queries and Indexes](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries.html) to see how AppEngine's database works.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use only one query, so that Django also generates only one query using a join.
Something like this should work:

```
Song.objects.filter(tags__name__in=taglist)
```

You may need to change some names from this example (most likely the `tags` in `tags__name__in`), see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/relations/.